# In Javascript, Check the array element include in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two array. 
 
**a_array= [2,3,4] 

b_array= [2,3,4,5]**

I'd like to know how to check all of a_array elements are included in b_array.
I used Jquery. **$.inArray(** a_array, b_array **)** but It can only be checked for one element.

Comment: What is `in_Array`? There's no native function called that in JavaScript.

Comment: @Andy Perhaps the OP is using jQuery.

Comment: Ah. sorry, yeah. I used jQuery

Comment: _.intersection(a_array, b_array);

http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

Comment: Oh! Duplicated question. Sorry for that. Actually I find out first, before I ask. But didn't see anything. May be I search with the wrong key word. Thank you all.

Comment: It's still a duplicate even if people marked the wrong one. See [set intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885660/2313887) which is efectively what you are asking.